# Maximize GNU Emacs on startup on Windows 8.1

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm running a 64-bit GNU Emacs version 25.0.50.1 on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 OS.

Adding the following to my `.emacs` does nothing:

```
(w32-send-sys-command 61488)
```

However, something like:

```
(global-set-key [(f4)] (function (lambda () "Maximize frame" (interactive) (w32-send-sys-command 61488))))
```

Works flawlessly; i.e. maximizes Emacs whenever F4 is pressed. However, I do not want to have to press F4 in order to do this -- I want it done automatically at startup. Why doesn't the first simple line work (it doesn't work even if it is the only line in my `.emacs`)?

Comment: Have you tried placing the first example at the very end of your `.emacs` file or perhaps placing it at the end of the `after-init-hook` -- i.e., give Emacs a chance to fully load before trying to maximize the frame?  In my own setup for Windows, I detect the size of the display by height `(display-pixel-height)` and width `(display-pixel-width)`, and then use `(set-frame-position frame 0 0) (set-frame-size frame 1890 1003 t)` -- the numbers for precise pixels vary depending upon which computer I am using -- I took the time to find the precise settings and hard-wired them.

Comment: **NOTE**:  The let-bound variable `frame` in the above example was pre-defined in my setup as the `(selected-frame)`.  I also detect Windows versions with:  `(equal (w32-version) '(5 1 2600))` and `(equal (w32-version) '(6 1 7601))`  Your version will be different, but `w32-version` will tell you the list equivalent.  And, I switch between computer systems, so I use `(eq system-type 'windows-nt)` and `(eq system-type 'darwin)`

Comment: @lawlist: As I said, even having `(w32-send-sys-command 61488)` alone in my `.emacs` did nothing. @Chris' solution worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time around the version 24 release, Emacs added a native function `toggle-frame-maximized`. This function doesn't take any arguments, but since the default state of Emacs it to have a non-maximized frame, on my Linux system simply adding

```
(toggle-frame-maximized)
```

to my init makes Emacs start up maximized.

As far as I know, this should also work on Windows.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot and happy holidays! Just for the record, I'm running a Git build of GNU Emacs from MSYS2: http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
(defun maximize-frame ()
"Maximize the current frame"
 (interactive)
 (w32-send-sys-command 61488))


(defun post-load-stuff ()
  (interactive)
  (maximize-frame)
)
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'post-load-stuff t)
```